How to select first level component fields in a single type on Strapi V5?
I have a single type called "landing" with one custom component. I'm trying to fetch only the fields I want from the component and I get an internal 500 server error when trying to get the "title" field.
I could fetch all the data I want with this query : "http://localhost:1337/api/landing?locale=fr&populate[0]=metadata&populate[1]=metadata.icon" which provide the complete response :
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "documentId": "w4z673xnhj4l65f5n52516js",
        "createdAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.097Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.097Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.108Z",
        "locale": "fr",
        "metadata": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "test",
            "description": "test description",
            "icon": {
                "id": 63,
                "documentId": "d4eozd44w0atb4snvx3z6u39",
                "name": "iconWorld.png",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 64,
                "height": 64,
                "formats": null,
                "hash": "icon_World_52392aee13",
                "ext": ".png",
                "mime": "image/png",
                "size": 2.32,
                "url": "/uploads/icon_World_52392aee13.png",
                "previewUrl": null,
                "provider": "local",
                "provider_metadata": null,
                "createdAt": "2024-10-13T09:30:23.800Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:34.798Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-10-13T09:30:23.800Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}

What I would like to do is to fetch only the title attribute from the metadata component and the url from the icon media
my query is "http://localhost:1337/api/landing?locale=fr&populate[metadata][populate][icon][fields][0]=url&populate[metadata][fields][0]=title"
first part of the query is working, as far as I try to add "&populate[metadata][fields][0]=title" I get
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    }
}

On the console, I can see this log
[2024-10-30 18:36:04.952] error: select distinct `t1`.`order`, `t0`.`id`, `t0`.`documentId`, `t0`.`title`, `t1`.`entity_id` as `__strapientity_id` from `components_common_metadata` as `t0` left join `landings_cmps` as `t1` on `t0`.`id` = `t1`.`cmp_id` and `t1`.`field` = 'metadata' where (`t1`.`entity_id` in (2)) order by `t1`.`order` asc - no such column: t0.documentId
SqliteError: select distinct `t1`.`order`, `t0`.`id`, `t0`.`documentId`, `t0`.`title`, `t1`.`entity_id` as `__strapientity_id` from `components_common_metadata` as `t0` left join `landings_cmps` as 
`t1` on `t0`.`id` = `t1`.`cmp_id` and `t1`.`field` = 'metadata' where (`t1`.`entity_id` in (2)) order by `t1`.`order` asc - no such column: t0.documentId
    at Database.prepare (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\methods\wrappers.js:5:21)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3._query (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\better-sqlite3\index.js:35:34)
    at executeQuery (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\internal\query-executioner.js:37:17)
    at Client_BetterSQLite3.query (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:154:12)
    at C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\transaction.js:371:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at trxClient.query (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\transaction.js:366:12)
    at Runner.query (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\runner.js:141:36)
    at ensureConnectionCallback (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\internal\ensure-connection-callback.js:13:17)
    at Runner.ensureConnection (C:\repo\aircastnews\aircastnews-front\aircastnews-strappy\node_modules\knex\lib\execution\runner.js:318:20)
[2024-10-30 18:36:04.954] http: GET /api/landing?locale=fr&populate[metadata][populate][icon][fields][0]=url&populate[metadata][fields][0]=title (16 ms) 500

I'm expecting to get
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "documentId": "w4z673xnhj4l65f5n52516js",
        "createdAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.097Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.097Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-10-30T16:59:38.108Z",
        "locale": "fr",
        "metadata": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "test",
            "icon": {
                "id": 63,
                "documentId": "d4eozd44w0atb4snvx3z6u39",
                "url": "/uploads/icon_World_52392aee13.png"
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}


To modify your query to fetch specific fields from your Strapi API, simply change the second index from 0 to 1, and "field" to "populate" in the following URL:
http://localhost:1337/api/landing?locale=fr&populate[metadata][populate][icon][populate][0]=url&populate[metadata][populate][1]=title


The query does not work : "400 - ValidationError Invalid - key url at metadata.populate.icon.populate.url"
Following the doc at https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select
"http://localhost:1337/api/landing?locale=fr&populate[metadata][populate][icon][fields][0]=url&populate[metadata][populate][icon][fields][1]=name"
works and get only "name" and "url" for metadata > icon
If I follow the same logic and try to get only the field "title" from metadata, it is not working
"http://localhost:1337/api/landing?locale=fr&populate[metadata][fields][0]=title"
error 500
